# How many trees and birds are there?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

There are 'X' number of Trees and 'Y' number Birds.

- If 1 bird sits on each tree then 1 BIRD will be left.
- If 2 birds sits    on each tree then 1 TREE will be left.

What is number of trees(X) and birds(Y)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are

> $4$ birds and $3$ trees

The first equation means that

> $Y = X+1$

The second equation means that

> $Y = 2(X-1)$

Hence

> $2(X-1) = X + 1 \Rightarrow X = 3 \Rightarrow Y=4$